# Accessing attributes of $scope elements created by $resource factory service in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to be able to access attributes of an object that was created via a $resource factory service (REST API).

*services.js:*

```
myApp.factory('userService', ['$resource', 'backendUrl', function($resource, backendUrl) {
  return $resource(backendUrl + '/api/users/:region/:name',
    {region: '@region', name: '@name'}
  );
}]);
```

*controllers.js:*

```
$scope.userInfo = userService.get({region: $routeParams.region, name: $routeParams.name});
```

In controllers.js, `userInfo` contains several attributes when displayed via `console.log($scope.userInfo)`, however I am unable to access those attributes using dot or bracket notation.

`console.log($scope.userInfo)` example output:

```
Resource {$promise: Object, $resolved: false, $get: function, $save: function, $query: function…}
$promise: Object
$resolved: true
id: 185
last_update: "2014-08-13T08:56:19.546"
name: "test_user"
region: "na"
```

Despite getting the above output, I am unable to access, for example, `$scope.userInfo.name`; it prints `undefined` when sent to console. I need some of the data in `userInfo` to craft further requests to the same API.

Am I missing something special about this being a Resource type of object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resources' get method is an async call. You can access properties after backend response.

You can test it with $resolved property.

```
$scope.userInfo = userService.get({region: $routeParams.region, name: $routeParams.name});
console.log($scope.userInfo.$resolved)
```

will always print false.

To access values after they are ready, resource's $promise callback can be used in two ways:

```
$scope.userInfo = userService.get({region: $routeParams.region, name: $routeParams.name}, function(userInfo) {
    console.log(userInfo.name);
    console.log($scope.userInfo.name); // will print the same
});
```

or:

```
$scope.userInfo = userService.get({region: $routeParams.region, name: $routeParams.name});
$scope.userInfo.$promise.then(function(userInfo) {
    console.log(userInfo == $scope.userInfo); // true
});
```

Also you can handle error conditions with resource.$promise.reject callback.
See more at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource